# Как быстро табулировать весь код в программе vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я знаю что в vscode есть горячие клавиши которые способны быстро табулировать весь код, но я их не знаю

Comment: Что значит "табулировать весь код"?

Comment: ну как бы сделать так чтобы везде перед строками стояло нужное количество пробелов

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-P -> Format document?

Comment: Да огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Shift+Alt+F или Ctrl-Shift-P -> Format document